# ASP.Net MVC Filter by Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I like to filter entity by using ASP.Net Identity (Roles). I used ASP.NET 4.5 MCV EF6.

My Tables are:

- Navigations (NavigationId, NavName, etc)
- NavigationRoles (NavigationId, RoleId, BlogRigth)

My filter in Navigations for one role  is:

```
var Nav= db.Navigations
                                .Join(db.NavigationRoles
                                ,n => n.NavigationId
                                ,nr =>nr.NavigationId
                                ,(n ,nr) => new { n , nr  })
                                .Where(x => x.nr.RoleId.Equals("dbd7d691-......"))
                                .Where(x => x.n.ParentId==1)
                                .Select(x=> x.n )
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList() ;
```

My users can have a collection of Roles, so I like to filter by these collection.
I get the collecten of Roles by :

```
 var UserRoleIDs = UserManager.FindById(UserId).Roles.Select(ri=> ri.RoleId);
```

How can I chain these in a good way?

I'm still new to LINQ, Lambda and MVC in general. If someone has a way to better this code, please feel free to add in your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trick here is to use [Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your list of user roles. Here's an example with your entities.

```
var UserRoleIDs = UserManager.FindById(UserId).Roles.Select(ri => ri.RoleId);


var query = from navRoles in db.NavigationRoles
            join nav in db.Navigations on navRoles.NavigationId equals nav.NavigationId
            where UserRoleIDs.Contains(navRoles.RoleId)
            select nav;


var distinct = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

I haven't used the LINQ express as I find it a lot easier to write lambda expressions when joins are involved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, at first I thought is not function, but when i check my tables everythink is Ok. Great